# A proof for isoperimetric inequality

Tags: differential-geometry

"Let $C\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a regular Jordan curve oriented so that the normal unit vector $N(p)$ points towards $I(C)$ (the interior of $C$) for every $p\in C$. Denoting with $L=Lung(C)$ the length of $C$ and with $A=AreaI(C)$ the area of $I(C)$, show that for every $\varepsilon >0$ sufficiently small, $C_{\varepsilon}=\{p+\varepsilon N(p):p \in C\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a smooth Jordan curve, such that $Lung (C_{\varepsilon})=L−2\pi \varepsilon$ and $Area I(C_{\varepsilon})=A−\varepsilon (L−\pi \varepsilon)$. Conclude that $L^2/A$ is minimum when $C$ is a circle (i.e. the circles maximize the enclosed area with the same length)."

I have been able to show what requested in the exercise, except for the last part: I am a bit confused about how to prove that $L^2/A\geq4\pi$ (which is the isoperimetric inequality) using the results proved before. May I have to consider the function $f(\varepsilon)=L_{\varepsilon}^2/A_{\varepsilon}$ where $L{\varepsilon}$ is the length of $C_{\varepsilon}$ and $A_{\varepsilon}$ is its area? (I found that $f'(\varepsilon)=0$ if $L-4\pi A=0$; does this mean anything?)

Thanks for any suggestion and help!

Comment: What is a "regular Jordan curve"? Why does it have unit normals at each point?

Comment: C is a regular curve in the plane, so the normal unit vector is well defined for every p in C. Moreover, we require C to be a Jordan curve, that is, a closed curve without self intersections.

Comment: With "regular" I mean that C admits a differentiable parametrization and the velocity vector is always non zero.